# JSF Deploy Exception: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss, inject

I just followed the ticket-monster tutorial(http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/Introduction/) and added a rest-service class to my solution.

```
package projectFoo.rest;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import projectFoo.model.party;


@Path("/partys")
@RequestScoped
public class partyService {

@Inject
private EntityManager em;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<party> getAllEvents() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<party> results =
            em.createQuery(
            "select e from party e order by e.name").getResultList();
    return results;
}
}
```

@Inject is underlined, returning: **"No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]"**

When I try to deploy the package, the process will fail and return the following message:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point.
```

Do I have to add a bean for the Entity Manager? How should this one look like? The tutorial doesn't mention this. Actually I couldn't find any definition of beans in the final ticket-monster project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `EntityManager` is found in an artifact for which CDI is not enabled (JPA provider jars do not have a `beans.xml` included).

You can either use the "good old" `@PersistenceContext` annotation insead of `@Inject`, or if you want to use `@Inject`, you will need to provide a producer for the EntityManager like this:

```
class Resources {
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @Produces
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
...
```